# How to wait result of suspend function?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

I need to add `freshCsrf` string to each request into form body. Uses `OkHttpClient` with `AuthInterceptor`. The problem is how to send request inside interceptor in order to get the `freshCsrf` string?

In code below occurs error

```
Suspend function 'getAuth' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
```

```
class AuthInterceptor(val authApi: IAuthService) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()

        val freshCsrf = authApi.getAuth().freshCsrf

        // ... add freshCsrf to form body
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

// Retrofit service
interface IAuthApi {
    @GET("/auth")
    suspend fun getAuth(): Auth
}
```

I try to use coroutine, but also failed because can't wait result. One of example with `async/await` case ended with error

```
Suspend function 'await' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
```

```
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        val freshCsrf = scope.async { authApi.getAuth().freshCsrf }
        freshCsrf.await()
        
        // ... add freshCsrf to form body

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

### Update 1

I confused with `runBlocking` description

> It is designed to **bridge** regular blocking code to libraries that are
> written in suspending style, to be used in **main functions** and in
> **tests**.

In one side, retrofit interface is suspending and I need to wait network result in order to continue creating other request (bridge - ok). But in the other side, it isn't main function or test. And many tutorials and articles tell that must to avoid `runBlocking` in production code. Can you explain it?

```
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()

        val freshCsrf = runBlocking {
            return@runBlocking authApi.getAuth().freshCsrf
        }
        
        // ... add freshCsrf to form body

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
```

Comment: Ideally, implement a `getAuthBlocking()` function that blocks and call that instead of `getAuth()`.

Comment: Yep. If `IAuthService` is Retrofit you can just remove the suspend modifier.

Comment: @JesseWilson in this case occurs error `Unable to create call adapter` from Retrofit

Answer (score 4):

Use `.execute()` instead of `.enqueue()` and it will perform the request synchronously.
`Interceptor` is not required, as CSRF protection usually resides in the HMTL `<head>`;
this would be something else, if the string would be served in the HTTP headers.

The relevent documentation: [`Interface Call<T>`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html).

Comment: Is there practical difference between `.execute()` and `runBlocking{}` case?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `runBlocking` then you will have to introduce second endpoint that returns `Call<Auth>` in the IAuthApi interface. `Call<Auth>` will allow you to run `execute()` function on it to run a request in synchronous (blocking) way.

[Call interface documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html)

Below how it can look like using `Call.execute`:

```
class AuthInterceptor(val authApi: IAuthService) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()

        val freshCrsf = authApi.getAuthCall().execute().let { authResponse ->
            if(authResponse.isSuccessful) {
                authResponse.body().freshCrsf
            } else {
                // TODO handle error for example you can read authResponse.errorBody()
                // and do something based on it
            }
        }

        // ... add freshCsrf to form body
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

// Retrofit service
interface IAuthApi {
    @GET("/auth")
    fun getAuthCall(): Call<Auth>

    @GET("/auth")
    suspend fun getAuth(): Auth
}
```

I think `runBlocking` in this case is not a bad option really. As documentation state it's used to bridge suspending code to the blocking one. Main function and tests for me are common use cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("user/list")
fun userListGet(): Call<UserPageResponse>
}


lifecycleScope.launch {
val response = apiInterface.userListGet().await()
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?